# Extra params with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

How can I send extra parameters with the connection in socket.io? So when a client connects, they send additional information, and server-side it is received as

```
io.on('connection', function(client, param1, param2, param3) {
    // app code
}
```

Comment: Why not get the client to send a `"init"` message when they connect?

Comment: You can't. The signature of the event handlers are not user-defined, the library defines them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a little trick which should work. First, you create your own Socket client that sends a message on first connection (containing all your additional info).

```
// Client side

io.MySocket = function(your_info, host, options){
  io.Socket.apply(this, [host, options]);
  this.on('connect', function(){
    this.send({__special:your_info});
  });
};
io.util.inherit(io.MySocket, io.Socket);

var my_info = {a:"ping"}
var socket  = io.MySocket(my_info);
```

Then on the server side, you modify your socket to listen for the special message and fire off an event when it does.

```
// Server side

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on('message', function(message){
    if (message.__special) {
      io.emit('myconnection', client, message.__special);
    }
  });
});

io.on('myconnection', function(client, my_info) {
  // Do your thing here
  client.on('message', ...); // etc etc
}
```

This is the technique I used to link my session handling into Socket.IO for a package I wrote.