# I have a video js file that I must pause using websockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

The problem is that I have a C++ Application that must send a message to a tcp server, which then sets a flag .The javascript client must keep on polling this server for the flag status , once the flag has been set. stop playing the video . I am really having trouble Implementing this ?

My websocket dies as I poll the tcp node js server

Video js client code:

```
function myTimer()
{  
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:7777');
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        //test(ex1);
        alert("test");
    });
}

var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
```

Server code node js:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(7777);
var flag = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('myClick', function (data) {
        socket.emit('myClick' , data);
    });
});
```

Comment: You may only open the socket once? No polling? Listen on data instead!

Comment: Hi Bergi my video is in a specific URL that I call from within video js in the client

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who wants a heads up to this question , I was making a mistake of not setting the sockets.io parameters correctly and this other stack overflow answer resolved my doubts

[Extra params with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284795/extra-params-with-socket-io)